# Can't open JSON in Excel because of NaNs

Tags: jquery, json, excel, csv, null

I have a huge JSON file I want to open in Excel (convert to CSV). But when I try to pass the file in Excel, it gives an error, that I have surplus signs in the JSON file. It's probably because of the NaNs in the JSON. Does anyone know, how to replace the NaNs with NULLs or how to open the JSON any other way in Excel? Thanks!

Comment: how are you importing this data?

Comment: I'm doing it with Excel Powerquery import and transform.